# Incorporating uncertainty in hypergeometric probability test

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, distributions, hypergeometric-distribution, false-discovery-rate

Wikipedia's page on [determining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution)  the hypergeometric probability describes the variables in the following way:

> N is the population size, 
>   K is the number of success states in the population,
>   n is the number of draws and
>   k is the number of observed successes

However, what if K and k are *predictions* that have some estimated 'false positive rate' (FPR). In other words, what if the 'success states' of both the overall and drawn populations are predictions that come along with some estimate of the FPR.

To put this in concrete terms, assume:

```
N = 50
K = 5
n = 10
k = 5
```

In this case, the probability of drawing exactly 5 'successes' from a sample of 10 is 0.0001189 (see Wikipedia reference: first example).

However, what if the FPR in the drawn and overall populations is, say 25%?

Is there a way to take this uncertainty into account when generating a p-value?